# When the site does go live, what exactly will change?

Tags: discussion, beta

From the Android Enthusiasts Beta to the actual implementation, what changes will exactly be taking place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see -- what happens when a site goes public:

- the site gets a custom design and favicon (no more generic sketchy-beta)
- it is eligible to have questions migrated to and from it from other sites
- the site will be promoted by sister sites in the network, through house ads and question migrations
- the reputation levels increase to standard, instead of the relaxed levels that are in place now.

I might have forgotten something, but I believe that's the major points.

Comment: Also on my list: **"Lock in."** A graduated site has progressed past the *trials* of a probationary period. As a fully-fledged site, it is much less likely to be cited for problems and shut down.